# Do ASPX pages have some hidden reference to a CSS style sheet?

Tags: css, asp.net, stylesheet

I've got an .aspx page that references a style sheet (visible when I view-source in the browser):

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bungalow.css">
```

But when I edit the file in VS 2012, it's not there.

Comment: Did you check the layout/master page?

Comment: in source-view, click the link to the css to view it. see if there are any comments. (not that i know of, to answer ur question. odd.)

Comment: Try a plain text search in VS2012 across the whole solution to try and track down where the file is referenced.